# Custom Icons - Hamburger Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, template10

How do I put my icons on the hamburger menu? I'm using it to put the icons that already exist: `Symbol="Home"`

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Home" />
    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Página Principal"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But now I wanted to use icons created by me!

Comment: `Symbol` is an enumeration. If you want to use your custom icons, I suggest you to use `Image` Control

Answer (score 1):

What you are using in your code is [SymbolIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon) which just has some icons defined and you cannot use it for your own defined icons.

If you take a look at [controls at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls) you will find that you have couple of ways of implementing own icon (apart from proposed *Image*):

- [BitmapIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon) where you can put *URI* to your file in assets,
- [FontIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon) where you can put *Glyph* from selected font,
- [PathIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pathicon) where you can put any *Geometry* as *Data* - this one resizes very nice.

Comment: Can you give me an example with my code?
`<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="HomePage"/>
</StackPanel>`

Comment: @FernandoSousaa In place of *SymbolIcon* put one of those above. Have you taken a look at MSDN, tried something - where are the problems?

Comment: My question is how do I indicate the location where I have my image
I have this now:
`<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <PathIcon Width="48"
                              Height="48"
                              ImageSource="/Assets/Untitled.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Logo" />
                </StackPanel>`

Comment: @FernandoSousaa *ImageSource* is an *URI*, try like this: `ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Untitled.png"`

Comment: Give an error: The member "ImageSource" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: @FernandoSousaa  Now I see that you have a pathicon there, probably should be: `<BitmapIcon Width="48" Height="48" UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Untitled.png"/>` - it's not hard to find those information over internet.